# Use groupby in Pandas to count things in one column in comparison to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Maybe groupby is the wrong approach. Seems like it should work but I'm not seeing it...

I want to group an event by it's outcome. Here is my DataFrame (df):

```
Status  Event
SUCCESS Run
SUCCESS Walk
SUCCESS Run
FAILED  Walk
```

Here is my desired result:

```
Event   SUCCESS FAILED
Run     2       1
Walk    0       1
```

I'm trying to make a grouped object but I can't figure out how to call it to display what I want.

```
grouped = df['Status'].groupby(df['Event'])
```

Comment: Please pay attention at @piRSquared's solution, it looks very neat and faster compared to others

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd do:

```
df.groupby('Event').Status.value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
```

Or use the `fill_value` argument:

```
df.groupby('Event').Status.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

[image]

Comment: yep, your solution is faster

Answer (score 10):

try this:

```
 pd.crosstab(df.Event, df.Status)

Status  FAILED  SUCCESS
Event                  
Run          0        2
Walk         1        1


len("df.groupby('Event').Status.value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)")
61

len("df.pivot_table(index='Event', columns='Status', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)")
74

len("pd.crosstab(df.Event, df.Status)")
32
```

Comment: that's a funny comparison! :)

Comment: The Zen of Python, number 3. Simple is better than complex.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative solution, using [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) method:

```
In [5]: df.pivot_table(index='Event', columns='Status', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
Out[5]:
Status  FAILED  SUCCESS
Event
Run          0        2
Walk         1        1
```

Timing against 700K DF:

```
In [74]: df.shape
Out[74]: (700000, 2)

In [75]: # (c) Merlin

In [76]: %%timeit
   ....: pd.crosstab(df.Event, df.Status)
   ....:
1 loop, best of 3: 333 ms per loop

In [77]: # (c) piRSquared

In [78]: %%timeit
   ....: df.groupby('Event').Status.value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
   ....:
1 loop, best of 3: 325 ms per loop

In [79]: # (c) MaxU

In [80]: %%timeit
   ....: df.pivot_table(index='Event', columns='Status',
   ....:                aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
   ....:
1 loop, best of 3: 367 ms per loop

In [81]: # (c) ayhan

In [82]: %%timeit
   ....: (df.assign(ones = np.ones(len(df)))
   ....:    .pivot_table(index='Event', columns='Status',
   ....:                 aggfunc=np.sum, values = 'ones')
   ....: )
   ....:
1 loop, best of 3: 264 ms per loop

In [83]: # (c) Divakar

In [84]: %%timeit
   ....: unq1,ID1 = np.unique(df['Event'],return_inverse=True)
   ....: unq2,ID2 = np.unique(df['Status'],return_inverse=True)
   ....: # Get linear indices/tags corresponding to grouped headers
   ....: tag = ID1*(ID2.max()+1) + ID2
   ....: # Setup 2D Numpy array equivalent of expected Dataframe
   ....: out = np.zeros((len(unq1),len(unq2)),dtype=int)
   ....: unqID, count = np.unique(tag,return_counts=True)
   ....: np.put(out,unqID,count)
   ....: # Finally convert to Dataframe
   ....: df_out = pd.DataFrame(out,columns=unq2)
   ....: df_out.index = unq1
   ....:
1 loop, best of 3: 2.25 s per loop
```

Conclusion: the @[ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278603/use-groupby-in-pandas-to-count-things-in-one-column-in-comparison-to-another/38279370?noredirect=1#comment63979020_38279370)'s solution currently wins:

```
(df.assign(ones = np.ones(len(df)))
   .pivot_table(index='Event', columns='Status', values = 'ones',
                aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
)
```

Comment: Can you test pivot_table with `sum` rather than `len`? I think `len` is slowing it down. `df.assign(ones = np.ones(len(df))).pivot_table(index='Event', columns='Status', aggfunc=np.sum, values = 'ones')`

Comment: @ayhan, it's interesting - i thought the `groupby()...value_counts()` solution should be faster...

Comment: I was surprised about crosstab actually. I'd expect it to be the fastest since it is designed exactly for this. It scales good though.

Comment: @ayhan, just checked pandas's `crosstab()` implementation - it uses `pivot_table(..., aggfunc=len)` or `pivot_table(..., aggfunc=aggfunc)` (if `aggfunc` was specified) internally ;)

Comment: Btw, `df.pivot_table(index='Event', columns='Status', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)` is a lot faster (probably because it doesn't require a new column) :)

Comment: @ayhan, that was my very first attempt, but it returns an empty DF

Comment: Interesting. I just timed it, I was sure that it was going to work.

Comment: @ayhan, interesting,  i'll need to remember this ;)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a NumPy based approach -

```
# Get unique header strings for input dataframes
unq1,ID1 = np.unique(df['Event'],return_inverse=True)
unq2,ID2 = np.unique(df['Status'],return_inverse=True)

# Get linear indices/tags corresponding to grouped headers
tag = ID1*(ID2.max()+1) + ID2

# Setup 2D Numpy array equivalent of expected Dataframe
out = np.zeros((len(unq1),len(unq2)),dtype=int)
unqID, count = np.unique(tag,return_counts=True)
np.put(out,unqID,count)

# Finally convert to Dataframe
df_out = pd.DataFrame(out,columns=unq2)
df_out.index = unq1
```

Sample input, output on a more generic case -

```
In [179]: df
Out[179]: 
  Event   Status
0   Sit     PASS
1   Run  SUCCESS
2  Walk  SUCCESS
3   Run     PASS
4   Run  SUCCESS
5  Walk   FAILED
6  Walk     PASS

In [180]: df_out
Out[180]: 
      FAILED  PASS  SUCCESS
Run        0     1        2
Sit        0     1        0
Walk       1     1        1
```