# Groupby value counts on the dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    (1, 1, 'term1'),
    (1, 2, 'term2'),
    (1, 1, 'term1'),
    (1, 1, 'term2'),
    (2, 2, 'term3'),
    (2, 3, 'term1'),
    (2, 2, 'term1')
], columns=['id', 'group', 'term'])
```

I want to group it by `id` and `group` and calculate the number of each term for this id-group pair.

So in the end I want to get something like this:

[image]

Anyway I can achieve this without looping?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

I use `groupby` and `size`

```
df.groupby(['id', 'group', 'term']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

[image]

---

## Timing

[image]

***1,000,000 rows***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=np.random.choice(100, 1000000),
                       group=np.random.choice(20, 1000000),
                       term=np.random.choice(10, 1000000)))
```

[image]

Comment: @jezrael thx, `size` is quicker too.  `crosstab` is oddly inefficient

Comment: And I am surprised that `crosstab` is so lazy ;)

Comment: @jezrael, `crosstab` uses `pivot_table` internally... ;)

Comment: @piRSquared - can you add to timings `df.groupby(['id', 'group', 'term'])['term'].size().unstack(fill_value=0)` ? It seems faster for me. Thanks.

Comment: @piRSquared - I try it in larger df and a bit faster (0.2ms, maybe it is same ;))

Comment: @jezrael all are same except for `crosstab`

Comment: @piRSquared How would you create the same table except with proportions of respective classes?

Answer (score 29):

using [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) method:

```
In [22]: df.pivot_table(index=['id','group'], columns='term', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
Out[22]:
term      term1  term2  term3
id group
1  1          2      1      0
   2          0      1      0
2  2          1      0      1
   3          1      0      0
```

Timing against 700K rows DF:

```
In [24]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [25]: df.shape
Out[25]: (700000, 3)

In [3]: %timeit df.groupby(['id', 'group', 'term'])['term'].size().unstack(fill_value=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 226 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit df.pivot_table(index=['id','group'], columns='term', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 236 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit pd.crosstab([df.id, df.group], df.term)
1 loop, best of 3: 355 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit df.groupby(['id','group','term'])['term'].size().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
1 loop, best of 3: 232 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit df.groupby(['id', 'group', 'term']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 231 ms per loop
```

Timing against 7M rows DF:

```
In [9]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10, ignore_index=True)

In [10]: df.shape
Out[10]: (7000000, 3)

In [11]: %timeit df.groupby(['id', 'group', 'term'])['term'].size().unstack(fill_value=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.27 s per loop

In [12]: %timeit df.pivot_table(index=['id','group'], columns='term', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.3 s per loop

In [13]: %timeit pd.crosstab([df.id, df.group], df.term)
1 loop, best of 3: 3.37 s per loop

In [14]: %timeit df.groupby(['id','group','term'])['term'].size().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.28 s per loop

In [15]: %timeit df.groupby(['id', 'group', 'term']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.89 s per loop
```

Comment: I was just trying to update timings with larger sample :-)

Comment: wow!  pivot seems just as efficient at larger scales.  I'll have to remember that.  I'd give you +1 but I already did a while ago.

Comment: So `size` was the alias that we forgot [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38279370/2285236) :)

Comment: @ayhan, very strange - this time the solution with `df.assign(ones = np.ones(len(df))).pivot_table(index=['id','group'], columns='term', values = 'ones', aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)` is bit slower - `1 loop, best of 3: 2.55 s per loop`

Comment: I think it is because you used `len` there, instead of 'size'. `len` is a Python function but the functions we pass as strings are aliases to optimized C functions.

Comment: @ayhan, i have the same timing if i use `df.shape[0]` instead of `len(df)`

Comment: @MaxU - can you add to timings `df.groupby(['id', 'group', 'term'])['term'].size().unstack(fill_value=0)` ? Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael, i've added a timing for this solution

Comment: @MaxU - very interesting, Iget same timings with fastest method, but you get different. Thank you for timings.

Answer (score 26):

Instead of remembering lengthy solutions, how about the one that pandas has built in for you:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'group', 'term']).count()
```

Comment: Maybe this used to work before, but it doesn't return any columns in pandas 1.5.2

Comment: @alibakhtiari, would love to see what columns your dataframe has, groupby count has been working since python existed and still does.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
print (pd.crosstab([df.id, df.group], df.term))
term      term1  term2  term3
id group                     
1  1          2      1      0
   2          0      1      0
2  2          1      0      1
   3          1      0      0
```

Another solution with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), reshaping by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df.groupby(['id', 'group', 'term'])['term'].size().unstack(fill_value=0)

term      term1  term2  term3
id group                     
1  1          2      1      0
   2          0      1      0
2  2          1      0      1
   3          1      0      0
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [48]: %timeit (df.groupby(['id', 'group', 'term']).size().unstack(fill_value=0))
100 loops, best of 3: 12.4 ms per loop

In [49]: %timeit (df.groupby(['id', 'group', 'term'])['term'].size().unstack(fill_value=0))
100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: wow wow wow, you are amazing. And it took you only 3 minutes (the same time it took me to write a loop, and less time then it took me to write this question). I would really appreciate if you can write some explanation of why this works, but most probably I will be able to understand it by myself in a few minutes.

Comment: In your case `crosstab` is better as `pivot_table`, because default aggregating function is `len` (it is same as `size`) and I think it is also faster solution. `Crosstab` use first argument as `index` and `second` of columns. Give me a time, I try add timings.

Comment: But I think better it is explain in [`docs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#cross-tabulations).

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use `value_counts` you can use it on a given series, and resort to the following:

```py
df.groupby(["id", "group"])["term"].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

or in an equivalent fashion, using the `.agg` method:

```py
df.groupby(["id", "group"]).agg({"term": "value_counts"}).unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Another option is to directly use `value_counts` on the DataFrame itself without resorting to `groupby`:

```py
df.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
df.assign(count=1).groupby(['id', 'group','term']).sum().unstack(fill_value=0).xs("count", 1)

term      term1  term2  term3
id group                     
1  1          2      1      0
   2          0      1      0
2  2          1      0      1
   3          1      0      0
```