# Value counts by multi-column groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a Pandas dataframe that I'm grouping by two columns: ID and Item. I am then keeping the last 5 occurrences in each group (maximum), and would finally like to calculate a ratio of the number of occurrences of one specific type.Specifically, I would like to calculate the count of 'U' for each ID-item divided by the total number of occurrences.

I am having trouble with the last step - I am not sure how to get from the general value counts below to a ratio for each ID-Item grouping. Any tips would be much appreciated - thank you!

```
d={'ID':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],'Item': ['box','box','ball','ball','box','box','box','ball','box','ball'],'Direction':['D','U','U','D','U','U','D','D','D','D']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

z=company_item['revision_arrow'].value_counts()

groups=df.groupby(['ID','Item'])
max_count=5
lastfive=groups.head(max_count).reset_index(drop=True)

#count_series=lastfive['Direction'].value_counts()
count_series=groups['Direction'].value_counts()
```

Comment: I believe the first answer in this question is relevant: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132742/groupby-value-counts-on-the-dataframe-pandas). Use `.size().unstack(fill_value=0)` on your groupby object. This will get you the occurrences of 'U' for each ID-item, then you can divide by the total number of occurrences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), you have the option to normalize the results.  You can use this parameter, and then index the resulting DataFrame to only include the `U` rows:

```
out = (df.groupby(['ID', 'Item'])
          .Direction.value_counts(normalize=True)
          .rename('ratio').reset_index())

out.loc[out.Direction.eq('U')]
```

```
   ID  Item Direction     ratio
1   1  ball         U  0.500000
2   1   box         U  0.666667
6   2   box         U  0.333333
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great on the sample code, but for some reason I get this error if I try to do it on my actual data: AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Direction'

Comment: @Z_D does your actual DataFrame have a column named `Direction`?

Comment: Man that was stupid! No it does not - thank you. Fixed now. This is a really nice solution - thanks for introducing this feature to me.

Comment: It's something I always run into when I switch between dummy and real data :) Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want calculate only count('U') for each ID group divided into all count('U'), you can use apply with your defined function:

```
d={'ID':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],'Item': ['box','box','ball','ball','box','box','box','ball','box','ball'],'Direction':['D','U','U','D','U','U','D','D','D','D']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)


def func(df):
    return len(df[df.Direction == 'U'])

df.groupby('ID').apply(func) / len(df[df.Direction == 'U'])
```

Output:

```
ID
1    0.75
2    0.25
```

You can group by ID and Item, if you need.